# How to adjust the view position when the keyboard opens in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

In forms that are longer than 50% of the screen area, inputs will appear underneath the keyboard.
I want to adjust the view to keep the selected input always visible when the keyboard shows and reset its position when the keyboard disappears.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The section [Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TextandWeb/TextandWeb.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH20-SW3) in the iPhone Application Programming Guide discusses how to receive notifications of keyboard display/undisplay, as well as how to keep your content visible (including sample code).

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a `UIScrollView`, you can use the [`-scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/scrollRectToVisible:animated:) to move to a particular portion of the view.

If you're in a `UITableView`, you can use the  [`-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:) to scroll to a particular row, or [`- scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:).

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding to manage Keyboards automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
#define kTextFieldMovementDistance      150.0 //You can set this according to your need
#define kMinimumMovementDuration        0.3f

- (void) slidingViewUpward: (BOOL) isSlidingUp
{
    CGFloat movementDistance = kTextFieldMovementDistance; 

    const float movementDuration = kMinimumMovementDuration;

    int movement = (isSlidingUp ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animation" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

When you want to slide the view in upwards Direction, or when the Keyboard became the first responder, the pass the bool value as `YES` otherwise `NO`.